# Error when using notify-send and exec

Tags: node.js

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('notify-send -t 5000 -i "Hello Karl"', function (err, stdout, stderr){
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (err !== null)
        throw err;
});
```

I get the error:

```
Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c notify-send -t 5000 -i "Hello Karl"
No summary specified.
```

If the command was for example `node -v` it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
notify-send -t 5000 "Hello Karl"
```

It was an error with the command I was feeding it.